# LinkedList multithreading creating separate instances in Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list

Code that illustrates my problem:

```
public class Linkedlisttest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Linkedlisttest test = new Linkedlisttest();
        test.go(args);
    }
    public void go(String[] args) {
        int cpus = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(cpus, cpus * 2, 1L,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        String numbersarray[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
        LinkedList<String> numbers = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(numbersarray));
        for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
            tpe.execute(new removeNumbers(numbers, index));
        }
    }
    class removeNumbers implements Runnable {
        LinkedList<String> localnumbers;
        int index;
        public removeNumbers(LinkedList<String> localnumbers, int index) {
            this.localnumbers = localnumbers;
            this.index = index;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(localnumbers.size() + " Thread#: " + index);
            while (localnumbers.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println(localnumbers.removeFirst() + " Thread#: " + index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output (which varies somewhat in which thread removes what element):

```
5 Thread#: 0
5 Thread#: 1
one Thread#: 0
three Thread#: 0
four Thread#: 0
five Thread#: 0
two Thread#: 1
```

I'm expecting `{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"}` to get removed twice, once by each thread. However, it seems like the `removeNumbers` Runnables are sharing the same `localnumbers` LinkedList. Why does this happen?  My understanding is that I've created two separate instances of `localnumbers`, one in each `removeNumbers` Runnable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing a reference to the same `LinkedList<String>` into both constructor calls, so each `localnumbers` is pointing to the same `List`. That's why both are removing from the same `List`, because you haven't actually copied it.

You will want to do something along the lines of:

```
LinkedList<String> numbers = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(numbersarray));
for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
    LinkedList<String> numbersCopy = new LinkedList<String>(numbers);
    tpe.execute(new removeNumbers(numbersCopy, index));
}
```

There are more efficient ways to make these copies. Note that even two calls to [Arrays.asList()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) using the same array will not be enough to truly create copies, since that method returns a `List` backed by the array. You will need to create copies of the `List` as in the loop above, or else use [System.arraycopy()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to copy the array at the beginning:

```
String[] numbersarray = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
String[] numbersarray2 = new String[numbersarray.length];
System.arraycopy(numbersarray, 0, numbersarray2, 0, numbersarray.length);
```

Comment: Right. Both instances of **removeNumbers** have a reference to the same instance of your list.

Answer (score 2):

Kublai is correct. If you want each **removeNumbers** instance to operate on it's own list you must make copies. So you **removeNumbers** constructor would create a copy of the list for processing. To make this even better / safer you should pass in an ImmutableList (Guava) or an unmodifiable List (via Collections).

Comment: +1 Good idea giving the copying responsibility to the constructor, and passing in something immutable.

Comment: why would passing in something immutable make it more safe?

Comment: No risk of one remover updating the passed list prior to it being sent to the next remover. In general, when dealing with concurrency, immutability is the way to go as it prevents any possibility for concurrent modification.